# Unable to List Available Docker Version

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to install Docker Containers
https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

I've SET UP THE REPOSITORY and everything looks good.

The section, INSTALL DOCKER CE
1. I did an "apt-get update"
3. Because I need to specify a specific docker version for Kubernetes

When I ran, "apt-cache madison docker-ce" to list the available docker version but I do not get anything back.  No errors or anything.

Am I doing something wrong or missing anything??
Has anyone ever encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

Check this alternative option

```
apt list -a docker-ce
```

Comment: When I ran your code, I get this root@kube-master:~# apt list -a docker-ce
Listing... Done
It doesn't provide me with any of the available Docker version that I can install with Kubernetes.  Am I missing something??

Answer (score 0):

I just re-run the add repository with the word "nightly" and/or "test", I'm able to see all the available docker version.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable nightly"
```